# Where Ebean created a new table?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I created application using Play Framework, and I created a model object Task. It looks like in a documentation:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity 
public class Task extends Model {

  @Id
  @Constraints.Min(10)
  public Long id;

  @Constraints.Required
  public String name;

  public boolean done;

  @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
  public Date dueDate = new Date();

  public static Finder<Long,Task> find = new Finder<Long,Task>(
    Long.class, Task.class
  ); 

}
```

The application is connected with a PostgreSQL database

```
datasource.pg.username=postgres  
datasource.pg.password=postgres  
datasource.pg.databaseUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/websocket  
datasource.pg.databaseDriver=org.postgresql.Driver  
datasource.pg.heartbeatsql=select 1
```

When I ran application for the first time, it asked me that do I wanted to create a new table. Of course I agreeded, but I can't find any new table in my local database named 'websocket'.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly, but just to be sure: the name of the new table will be `task`.

In a Linux terminal you can check it with:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d websocket

websocket# \d
```

And the output will be something like this:

```
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       |   Type   | Owner 
--------+-----------------+----------+---------
 public | task            | table    | postgres
 public | task_seq        | sequence | postgres
 public | play_evolutions | table    | postgres
(3 rows)
```